# Cassandra - How to insert an UUID

Tags: cassandra, uuid

I'm using Cassandra  0.6.4 and I'm trying to insert an UUID for a column and I get an exception of: InvalidRequestException(why:UUIDs must be exactly 16 bytes). What is the correct way to insert an UUID? Thanks!

**My column family is defined as:**

```
<ColumnFamily CompareWith="TimeUUIDType" Name="Comments"/>
```

**Code Snippet:**

```
        try {
            ColumnPath colPathname = new ColumnPath(COLUMN_FAMILY);
            colPathname.setColumn(colName.getBytes(ENCODING));
            client.insert(KEYSPACE, rowKey, colPathname, colValue, System.currentTimeMillis(), ConsistencyLevel.ONE);

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            ..
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same problems as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450560/timeuuid-with-cassandra-and-lazyboy/3453406#3453406). Same solution :)

(short version: you are confusing row key with column name/key)